# Set layer order function not found

Tags: wms, openlayers

I am trying to set the Index of a wms layer called "landsat1". It draws on top by default, and I want to move it down the order. I have tried

```
landsat1.setZIndex(1)
```

But I get an error "function not found". Im using ol 3.11.0. According to the [api documentation](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/examples/layer-z-index.html), the function is experimental....but it doesn't seem to work for any version that has this function....other functions like landsat1.getProperties() works fine....why does this function not work? Or is there a better way to set the zindex om the wms layer?

Comment: Do you have a jsFiddle? It works fine for me in here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.11.2/examples/arcgis-tiled.html typing this in the console changes the layer sequence: map.getLayers().item(0).setZIndex(1)

Comment: This function works fine for me too. We could help you with some code I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I dint know about this function, maybe it is a progress I am not aware. But I ll tell what I am using so far to achive what your want.

```
//get the layers collection of your map
var layersColl = map.getLayers();
//you know your layer is at index 0 and you want to move it a index 1
var idxFrom = 0;
var idxTo = 1;
//this should return your landsat1 layer
var lyrToChangeIndex = layersColl.removeAt(idxFrom);
//once removed can be placed in the index you want to place it
layersColl.insertAt(idxTo,lyrToChangeIndex);
```

Comment: Thanks pavlos, those functions are a good way around...but for some strange reason my raster tilewms  "landsat1" layer always stays on top.

Comment: when you call `var lyrToChangeIndex = layersColl.removeAt(idxFrom);` does this returns the layer landsat1????? You must provide some code to find out what is wrong. It propably has to do with the way you declare your layer.

Comment: Yeah ...your right. I was using an api example that had the layer embeded inside a angularjs module. I should have provided a link to the example api code. My appoligies. Thanks Pavlos, bartvde & Alexis for taking the time to help.